# Issue in adding values to dropdown using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the below code I have dropdown that I want to fill the dropdown values using ajax but in my case I can get the values but it's not binding in dropdown.

```
function Bind() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //HTTP method
        url: "HoardReports.aspx/BindProduct", //page/method name
        data: "{'LocationID':'" + $('#<%= ddlLocation.ClientID %>').val() + "','ProductType':'" + $('#<%= ProdValrrodType.ClientID %>').val() + "'}", //json to represent argument
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            alert(msg.d);

            var splitVal = msg.d;
            var Location = splitVal.split(';');
            var length = Location.length;
            alert(length);


            var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=dpSourceProduct.ClientID %>');
            alert(dropDown);
            for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                alert('loop');
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = Location[i];
                alert(option.text); // i can get the values
                option.value = Location[i];
                alert(option.value);
                dropDown.options.add(option);//values are not added
            }
        }
    });

}

<editable:EditableDropDownList ID="dpSourceProduct"  runat="server" Style="width: 70%; height:29px"  EnableViewState="true" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value=='--Select--'){this.value='';}" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='--Select--';}"/>
```

Comment: what is not binding? events?

Comment: @Tushar values are not getting bind to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=dpSourceProduct.CLientID%>');
```

to

```
var dropDown = document.getElementById('dpSourceProduct');
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uz62trk/)

Comment: are you getting your dropdown in variable "dropdown"?

Comment: I think you are not getting your dropdown in variable , Try this now. This might help you .

Comment: issue is not solved in my page source i can  see  <input type="text" value="--ALL--" id="MainContent_dpSourceProduct" name="MainContent_dpSourceProduct" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" style="width: 70%; height: 29px;" Style="width: 70%; height:29px" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value=='--Select--'){this.value='';}" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='--Select--';}"/>

Comment: This is not a dropdown's source . copy your dropdown sourceand paste it here. This is input type="text" a textbox. find "<select ......></select>" in your page source.

Comment: You will have a <select> just above this input . Try finding it.

Comment: $("#MainContent_dpSourceProduct").combobox( {source: ["--ALL--"], name: "MainContent_dpSourceProduct_list", autopostback: false, autoselectFirstItem: false} );

Comment: No , it must be like this <select id="*" name="*">

Comment: There is no Select tag

Comment: Oh sorry , its my mistake . I thought you are talking about browsers page source. You fill it after running your application in browser.

Comment: It is browser page source. I am filling the data after running browser

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
dropDown.appendChild(option);
```

like:

```
function Bind() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //HTTP method
        url: "HoardReports.aspx/BindProduct", //page/method name
        data: "{'LocationID':'" + $('#<%= ddlLocation.ClientID %>').val() + "','ProductType':'" + $('#<%= ProdValrrodType.ClientID %>').val() + "'}", //json to represent argument
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {

            alert(msg.d);

            var splitVal = msg.d;
            var Location = splitVal.split(';');
            var length = Location.length;
            alert(length);


            var dropDown = document.getElementById('<%=dpSourceProduct.ClientID %>');
            alert(dropDown);
            for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                alert('loop');
                var option = document.createElement("option");
                option.text = Location[i];
                alert(option.text); // i can get the values
                option.value = Location[i];
                alert(option.value);
                dropDown.appendChild(option);//here
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Issue is not solved on viewing my page source    <input type="text" value="--ALL--" id="MainContent_dpSourceProduct" name="MainContent_dpSourceProduct" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left" style="width: 70%; height: 29px;" Style="width: 70%; height:29px" onfocus="javascript: if(this.value=='--Select--'){this.value='';}" onblur="javascript: if(this.value==''){this.value='--Select--';}"/>